# "bring" sudo into front?

Tags: linux, sudo

I have a very simple task: change all files' permission which are located in a specific folder:

```
find in_this_directory -type f -exec sudo chmod 0664 {} \;
```

While this works, it calls `sudo` on every shot which makes a huge impact on my system as *journalctl* logs all sudo accesses:

```
mycomp sudo[20047]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

This line above comes a million times if there are million files `in_this_directory`.

I could do

```
sudo find in_this_directory -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} \;
```

but this one does something else, and it will fail on the first shot where the file to be changed doesn't have *0777* and doesn't belong to current user.

Are there any better solutions than waiting for these *sudo* operations to conclude?

Comment: What makes the second version fail?

Comment: I believe**d** that `exec chmod ...` creates a *subshell* which doesn't inherit sudo rights

Comment: It doesn't create a subshell in the usual sense, but subshells inherit sudo rights just like any other subprocess does (as sudo literally just makes the process run as UID 0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo find ... -exec chmod` will usually achieve the same thing. The privileges granted by sudo are inheritable, as it does nothing more than make the process run as a different user (usually UID 0) which is always inherited.

The only times it'll behave differently is if a) your regular user doesn't have permissions to descend into some subdirectories (in which case `sudo find` will still descend into them), or b) you're using conditions like `-readable` that depend on the current UID.

For `chmod` and all other commands which accept multiple file names as their last argument, GNU find supports the `+` terminator which will run the command with as many files at once as possible:

```
find ... -exec chmod 0664 {} +
```

(For operating systems that don't support this extension, `xargs` could do the same thing, but it's a bit harder to handle filenames with spaces in them
– usually `-print0` or `xargs -d` won't work on such systems either.)